# MongoDB c# sharp Property vs Field vs Member vs Element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Looking into Custom Serialization, what's the difference between

```
A "Property" BsonClassMap.MapProperty
A "Field" BsonClassMap.MapField
A "Member" BsonClassMap.MapMember
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer should cover it:

[What is the difference between a Field and a Property in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c)

C# fields are meant to be hidden. Properties expose fields.